# Array compare and substitution

Tags: php

I have these arrays `$arr1` and `$arr2`

```
$arr1 = array(
                    'tn' => 'Tunisia',
                    'us' => 'United States',
                    'fr' => 'France');

$arr2 = array(
                    'tn' => 'Tunisia',
                    'us' => 'United States',
                    'fr' => 'France',
                    'mx' => 'Mexico',
                    'eu' => 'Europe' );
```

I want to compare `$arr1` with `$arr2` and if the keys in `$arr2` does not exist in `$arr1`, the keys should be deleted from `$arr2`. and the resulting array of $arr3 should be same as $arr1.

```
$arr3 = array(
                    'tn' => 'Tunisia',
                    'us' => 'United States',
                    'fr' => 'France');
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this?

Comment: Forgive me if I've got this wrong, but you want to `XNOR` the arrays, which will always make a copy of the first array. That seems a little pointless to me.

Comment: Er... `$arr3 = $arr1`. What do you _actually_ want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $arr3 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

read this [url once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

may be its help full